# Verify if an email exists in database of the website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to verify if the email I am using exists in a website.

I tried posting the email with random password and then from the response, using a search method, I want to see if a string like "email invalid" is present.

If it exists then it's invalid; if not then it's a valid email and so it exists in the database of the website.

I tried this, for example, for `facebook.com` - but I'm looking for a generic method for other websites:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://www.facebook.com")
header = {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}
user = {user: {
               email: 'example@gmail.com',
               password: "some_password"
                  }
        }
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
request.body = user.to_json
response = http.request(request)
puts response
puts request.body
source = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
puts source
```

Comment: I would advise you to change your gmail password immediately because you have just exposed it to internet,if that is a real gmail box

Comment: You're not going to get what you want this way. As a matter of fact, you wont get this at all from facebook. They don't respond at all with whether or not the email exists. If the email OR the password is invalid, they'll always respond with "Email or password is invalid". Otherwise they would have a security risk on their hands

Comment: You have not actually asked a question

Comment: [Change your password immediately. It is still visible in the question revisions.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50932829/revisions)

Comment: guys they are random password and email they does not exist

Comment: well any suggestion to do it ?? not for facebook because i put it as an example  but on other websites just to verify if the email exist in the database or no

Comment: What's wrong with getting a subpoena from a judge and sending that to the website operator? Seems a lot easier IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> Not for facebook because I put it as an example but on other websites just to verify if the email exist in the database

This is not always possible. You can only achieve this on a case-by-case basis for a given website. There are several different approaches you could try (as discussed below). You may also find that the website tries to rate limit/block your requests, depending on what you're doing -- for example, by adding a **captcha**, which (in theory) must require human intervention to pass.

Some possible ways to determine whether an email exists in a website's database are:

- Try to log in (with a bad password), and see if the response (e.g. error message) indicates whether the email exists.
- Try to reset the password, and see if the response (e.g. information/error message) indicates whether the email exists.
- Try to log in several times (with a bad password), and see if anything indicates that the account has been/will soon be *locked*.
- Try to sign up a new account, and see if anything indicates "this account already exists"
- Try to "add/contact/refer a friend" from inside the website; see if this indicates whether that user has an account.
- ... And so on.

In general, there will always be a trade-off here between the website being user-friendly vs secure: On the one hand, giving helpful error messages like "wrong password" vs "unknown email" is helpful; whereas on the other hand it's insecure for the website to leak information.

Hence why I began this answer by saying "it's not always possible". It depends how each website has been designed.

For example, rails applications using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication will, by default, expose information in ways such as the above. But if you choose to set Devise's `config.paranoid = true`, then error messages become generic and won't leak this data.

You could also try to figure this out by the response time: Sometimes, a (badly designed) website will *take longer to respond* with e.g. a failed login attempt or password reset request, if the email exists.

For more information, see: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_(OWASP-AT-002)

---

I have provided the above information for educational purposes such as how to build a secure website; in general I would *not* advocate trying to "expose" data by any of the above methods, against a website you do not own.

If you have a legal need to reveal all emails held by another company's website, I would strongly advise requesting access (through the legal system if necessary) rather than trying to leak it via security flaws!